# What are these bus/tag connectors for?

Tags: connector

I have a pair of connectors that mate with each other.  One is labeled BUS, the other TAG.  What are they for?

[image: bus-tag connectors]

Comment: Not enough information. What does this have to do with retro computing? What is the context? Are you trying to identify equipment, or do we know what systems they come from? Because there are a lot of hardware widgets out there.

Comment: I was hoping the picture would be sufficient. The Amdahl sticker suggests mainframe computer hardware from 20+ years back. I was wondering what they were and what they were used for.

Comment: So, a google search for that part number gets relevant hits. Did you try that?

Comment: A google search for "amdahl 312508-203" returns two hits, both product lists that only add the word "terminator" to the set of available knowledge. Dropping the "-203" expands the number of results, but it's still just part lists. Was there a result that you found particularly enlightening?

Comment: I got 4 hits, all suggesting these are bus terminators. Given these are Amdahl, they are going to be almost identical to IBM 360 equipment.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360#Channels We are still using a bus and tag connection between an old mainframe system and a Windows server.

Comment: @MarkF: Why don't you turn that comment into an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, these are bus and tag terminators for mainframe channels that used to run at 3MB/sec speeds.  Used as late as 1998 in P/390 development systems.  The IBM and Amdahl terminators are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

I guess (is that allowed as an answer?) that these are bus terminating resistors. High speed signals are usually passed along impedance matched transmission lines, the termination resistor mostly removes any reflections from an unused port.

Comment: Any idea why there would be two different types of terminators? I would guess some sort of asymmetric I/O setup, but it seems odd that the connectors can be physically attached to each other... I don't know if that's deliberate or just an artifact of the design (e.g. a desire to reduce manufacturing costs by using the same cases for both).  Peeking in the sides, they both have rows of resistors, but the resistors in BUS are different from those in TAG.

Comment: These will be pretty much identical to DCC bus terminators for IBM 360 and similar HP products. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360

Comment: Aha! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360#Byte-multiplexor_and_selector_channels in particular.

Comment: @fadden -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_and_Tag for the two types